# How can we handle multiple requests for event booking with limited seats and high concurrency?

Tags: database-design, concurrency, system

I have an event with 10K seats and there are hundreds of concurrent requests trying to book the event.

If I try to use transaction -  block the event row and add participant while retrying other waiting transactions. In this case, other users might have to wait a long time before their transaction succeeds.

Another solution can be using a FIFO queue, but I need to serve customers at the same time. The response should be synchronous.

Any idea on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Ticketing web sites that I have used, allowed me to _reserve_ tickets without paying. Then, I was given five or ten minutes in which to pay for the tickets, or else lose the reservation.

Comment: yes, but there is no need to block the spot. Just enter the event.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, "Just enter the event." Maybe that means I don't understand your original question. If "other users...have to wait a long time..." What are they awaiting?

Comment: Also, maybe I don't understand what you mean by "transaction." I'm not a database guy, but I thought that [_transactions_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) were non-blocking. Two clients each open a transaction (e.g., to buy tickets), each try to update the same records in the database, then each try to _commit_ their transaction. Only one of the commits can succeed. The clients _race_ each other to see who will get the tickets, but I didn't think that either client ever has to _wait_ for the other to finish any step in the process.

Comment: yes, transactions are non-blocking, but you can retry when you fail to acquire the lock on a certain record.  That way both clients can be served without throwing errors to one of them.